# What does it mean when a register is in brackets in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm learning 32-bit 8086 assembly (for class) and I'm going over one of the sample programs. What does it mean when a register is enclosed in brackets?

```
mov ebx, [ebx + 4]
```

Also, is the 4 a literal? (Are we moving "the value of ebx plus four" into ebx?)

Comment: In case your next question would be about `lea`; `lea` works differently, it puts the address in the destination register, not something from memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is equivalent to the following C code (assuming 32-bit `int`):

```
ebx = // whatever puts a value into ebx
ebx = *(int *)((char *)ebx + 4)
```

Or if you prefer,

```
ebx = *((int *)ebx + 1) // with C's type-aware pointer arithmetic
```

So we end up with the following:

```
unsigned char *memory; // byte-addressable machine memory

EBX = [memory[ebx + 7] | memory[ebx + 6] | memory[ebx + 5] | memory[ebx + 4]]
       most significant byte                          least significant byte
```

Note that this result would be different if x86 were big-endian instead of little-endian.

You might think it's weird to use `ebx` as both a pointer and a value, but it's not.  The pointer isn't needed any more, so we re-use its register to hold a value.  Assembly language doesn't have types.

Answer (score 0):

It is the value in memory at the address stored in `ebx` plus four bytes.

Comment: So the value of four bits after ebx?

Comment: Four bytes, not four bits.

Comment: Just to clarify: `ebx = ebx[4]`, yes?

Comment: leftfold posted it was a char*.

Comment: Ok, I guess that got deleted before I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

`mov ebx, [ebx + 4]` 
 means we are taking 4 bytes from the address specified by value in ebx register plus 4.
 For example, if ebx = 040404040h, we would be  taking 4 bytes starting at memory location 040404044h (040404040h + 04h), and putting it into register ebx.